# Calculate intersection of a line with a plane

Tags: intersection

I was reading something about: “Intersection of a line with a plane”. But I don’t fully understand how to calculate it on their way.

The goal is to calculate where the plane and the line will “cross”. These items are given:

- The eye is in position: O(0,0,-10)
- A point of a 3D-object is P(10,20,30)
- The screen has the equation z=0

I have a questions about how they calculate this:

[image]

This part is clear. That is the location form the eye (vector representation).

[image]
They specify the location of the plane, there is nothing strange here (vector representation).

[image]
Now they calculate what part of the line will cross, how did they calculate this? How did they know a = 1/4? And b = 10/4?

This is everything that was given.

Comment: [This SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5666222/3d-line-plane-intersection/5666547#5666547) might help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

linear systems of N variables can be solved if you have N equations.

```
x = 10ɑ
y = 20ɑ
z = -10 + 40ɑ
x = β
y = 2β + μ
z = 0
```

6 equations, 6 unknowns. You can solve for all 6. In fact, generally you can just combine the x/y/z parts and say

```
10ɑ = β
20ɑ = 2β + μ
-10 + 40ɑ = 0
```

and get 3-variable system in ɑ,β,μ. Once you get a value for ɑ, you can plug back in to P<sub>intersection</sub> = P<sub>lineEye</sub> + ɑ * P<sub>lineDirection</sub> to get x,y, and z.

Answer (score 3):

It's easier to think of this using vector maths.

The plane equation is `N.P = -D` for all points on the plane.

Therefore, the intersection point must satisfy this. If our point P is defined by the line equation `P = P0 + tQ` (where `Q` is the line's direction and t is the distance along the line) we can sub this in:

```
N.(P0 + tQ) = -D
```

The dot product is [bilinear](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product#Properties):

```
t(N.Q) + (N.P0) = -D
```

rearrange for `t`:

```
t(N.Q) = -D - N.P0
t = (-D - N.P0)/N.Q
```

and then plug your `t` back in to the line equation to get the crossing point.

From this we can intuitively read a couple of simple properties:

If the line's direction and the plane's normal are perpendicular there is no crossing. `N.Q` is zero, which would be a divide by zero.

`-D - N.P0` describes how 'far' `P0` is from the plane in the direction of the plane's normal. N.Q then describes the ratio between the direction of the plane and the direction of the line - the more parallel the direction and normal, the faster it will intersect.