# Determining IF & WHERE a line intersects with a 2D plane (in 3D space)

Tags: java, mathematics

The following problem I'm working on is for one of my favorite past-times: game development.

---

**Problem:** We're in 3D space. I'm trying to determine if a line between two vectors in said space is passing through a circle; the latter of which consists of: center vector, radius, yaw & pitch.

In order to determine that, my aim is to convert the circle to a plane which can either be infinite or just have the diameter of the circle for all it's sides.

Should the line between the two vectors in fact pass through that plane, I am left with the simple task of determining whether that intersection point is within the radius of the circle, in which case I can return either true or false.

---

**What's already working:** I have my circles set up and the general framework is there. The circles are appearing/rendered in the 3D space exactly as specified, great!

---

**What was already tried:** Copied some github gist codes and tried to make them work for my purposes. I kinda worked, sometimes at least. Unfortunately due to the nature of how the code was written, I had no idea what it was doing and just scrapped all of that. Researched the topic a lot, too. But due to me not really understanding the language people speak when talking about line/plane intersections, I could have read the answer without recognizing it as such.

---

**Question:** I'm stuck at line intersections. No idea where to go and how it works logically! So, where do I go from here and how can one comprehend all of this?

---

**Note:** I'm working with Java, but I'm not looking for spoon-fed code. It's a logical issue I'm trying to get past. If explained well enough, I will make the code work with trial and error!

Comment: Something like this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5666222/3d-line-plane-intersection

Comment: I've linked this question to [past answers we have on this topic](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/48765/39518). If you have any trouble implementing these answers in your game, please edit your question to show us where you're stuck, and we can re-open it to help you over that obstacle.